# css3 z-index problems, not working?

Tags: css, z-index

Im working on a uni project and need  my own images to form the backgrounds of a few pages. I have a key logo, a next and a back button, then the image. I would like the image to lay behind all these elements. i have assigned each element a positioning of relative/absolute and a z-index. However the image is still being pushed beneath these other elements. Any advice? I'll find my relative CSS / HTML and put it below.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/key.jpg"  width="3%" height="3%"/>
</div>

<div class="next">
<a href="scene2.html"> Next</a>
</div>

<div class="back">
<a href="abduction.html"> Back</a>
</div>

<div class="backing">
<img src="images/scene1.jpg"  width="800" height="800"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
#logo {
    position:relative;
    z-index:200;
}

.backing {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    float:left;
}

.next .back {
    position:relative;
    z-index:180;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backing element is actually behind your other elements, it's just that it's underneath it. If you put the backing element first in your HTML document it is underneath the rest of the page.

[image]

One alternative would be setting the background-image property of the body tag instead of setting z-indices for all of your elements.

Is there a reason you aren't doing this already?

To set the background of the body tag from HTML (advisable if you have many pages with different backgrounds)

`<body style="background-image: url('background1.png')">`

If you change the page using AJAX then you could set the background image using

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = "background1.png";`

Comment: The only reason i havent already is because i thought in CSS if i were to change the background-image of the body tag, that would mean that that specific image chosen would be the back ground for all the pages. Which is not what i want. I want to be able to control different backgrounds for different pages. Can you recommend how best to do this? Thank you!

Comment: If your website reloads for each page then you could just set the background-image in a style attribute for each page. If it doesn't reload for each page then you could use javascript to set the background image

`<body style="background-image: url('background1.png');">`

and `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "background1.png";`

Comment: If i follow ur suggestion and set the image as the background in html. is there a way to further style it? for example, not have it repeating the image, just have it once. and in the centre, with a margin at the top? Ideally i really do just want it in a div, behind the other elements... just cant seem to get it to work!